# Unusable links with onmouseover()

Tags: javascript

I try to make a displaying list with onmouseover() with some links but they don't work when I click on:

```
<script language="javascript">
function displayList()
{
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = 'More<br/><ul><li><a href="currency.php">Currency converter</a></li><li><a href="contactus.php">Contact us</a></li></ul><div id="quit" onmouseout="hideList();">Close</div>';
}

 function hideList()
{
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = 'More';
}
</script>
<div id="list" onmouseover="displayList();">More</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work?" You have a bunch of useless tags, I'm getting rid of them.

Comment: On the div element, if you put onclick instead of onmouseover, the links are working. The problem is obvious in the onmouseover, but I am not sure why...

Comment: The click event is lost because you're resetting the innerHTML. But I can't understand why myself: [onmouseover fired before click and mouseout event?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9932550/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a work around:

```
<script language="javascript">
function displayList()
{
document.getElementById('list').setAttribute('onmouseover','');

document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = 'More<br/><ul><li><a href="currency.php">Currency converter</a></li><li><a href="contactus.php">Contact 

us</a></li></ul><div id="quit" onmouseout="hideList();">Close</div>';
}

 function hideList()
{
document.getElementById('list').setAttribute('onmouseover','displayList();');
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = 'More';
}
</script>
<div id="list" onmouseover="displayList();">More</div>
```

Comment: It closes, but you have to do mouseout on the "Close" text, down on the y-axis. Depends where you have put this html code on your page. I've tried this isolated on a separate html page, and it works fine.