# onmouseover fired before click and mouseout events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mousemove

[Unusable links with onmouseover()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9930818/1048572) got an interesting question, when I tried to answer it. After some logging experiments, I've set up http://jsfiddle.net/RnGxP/1/. The last two examples work as expected, the hide when clicking on "Close" or leaving the "Close" div.

The first two examples set a new `innerHTML` to the div *whenever* the mouse moves in it (I'd never do that myself, but...).
So, when moving the mouse into one of them they get expanded. And moving the mouse further on a link or the "close" div, more move events get fired.

But then, clicking on the close button in the second example - without moving the mouse -, instead of a click event two mousemove events are fired! **What exactly happens here?** I can understand that the click event gets lost in some way (loosing its target?) when resetting `innerHTML`, but why is the mousemove event **fired before**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rewriting the `innerHTML` of the `div` element in the `mouseover` event. This means that each time you move the mouse it is in fact moving over a new node, which triggers a new `mouseover` event on that node, which bubbles up to the `div` element, which rewrites the `innerHTML` etc. etc.

So by the time the `mouseout` event fires on the inner `div`, the `mouseover` event has already rewritten the `innerHTML` on the outer `div`, and so the inner `div` has no parent...

What you really want to use is the `mouseenter` event (and presumably the `mouseleave` event on the inner `div`), which used to be proprietary to Internet Explorer but according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mouseenter) Firefox 10 and Opera 11.10 support it too.

Comment: OK, that might explain the behaviour for mouseout. But what I was really curious about is the click event (second div). Clicking without moving triggers two mousemove events, as can be seen in the console (?), but no alert from any click handler (?).

Comment: @Bergi Your mouseout event handler tries to set its parent's displayed property to false. But it doesn't have a parent, because its parent's mouseover event handler removed it. So the click handler throws a null reference exception. (At least, it does here.)